# Codeigniter and Ms access database connection

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, ms-access

Is there anyway is available to connect Ms-Access DB with codeignite framework.

I am Using Ubuntu I want to connect Ms-Access DB from remote windows machine using codeigniter framework. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1):

You used ms access database as a file like mydb.mdb

```
you are not connect to remotely access database.
because ms access database is used as a file.
```

Comment: This give some idea. But this connection set up for same machine i want to connect remote machine